# Renaming the Null value when using Rollup

Tags: sql, rollup

I have this script that is a test for creating dynamic 'Data Entry Signature Verification' worksheeet. I would like to place a 'Total' in place of 'NULL'.
This is what I have found online in different forums but I cannot replace it.

```
USE [LA_VOTER]    
GO    
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Temp].[dmv_import]    Script Date: 6/14/2018 
11:23:09 AM ******/    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON    
GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON    
GO    

ALTER PROCEDURE [Temp].[dmv_import]    
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here    
     @date date = null    
     ,@import_type varchar(5) = null        
AS    
BEGIN    
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
declare @date_work date     
if @date is null     
set @date_work = getdate()    
else    
Set @date_work = @date         
SELECT case when convert(varchar(6),vi.import_code) = null then 'Total' else vi.import_code end as 'Category'    
,sum(case when convert(date,vi.createdate,101) = @date_work then 1 else 0 end) as 'received'    
,sum(case when convert(date,vi.processed_date,101) = @date_work then 1 else 0 end) as 'processed'    
FROM DIMSNet.dbo.voter_import vi    
WHERE     
vi.import_type in ('INET', 'DUP', 'DMV')    
AND vi.import_type = @import_type     
AND import_code < 13     
GROUP BY import_code with rollup     
END
```

When run, this script outputs the following:

[image]

Th script is mostly working.

What I am trying to do is get the NULL value in the first column to calculate the total rollup of the script. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue? Kinda need a question to get an answer.

Comment: To replace the 'NULL' in the output with 'Total'